# lambda parameter deduced incorrect

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, c++17

why is this code incorrect under C++14 or even C++17?

```
template <typename T>
function<T(T, T)> ReturnLambda () {
    return [] (T x, T y) { return x*y; };
    // return [] (auto x, auto y) { return x*y; };    // also incorrect
}


int main() {
    auto f = ReturnLambda();
    cout << f(3, 4) << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) only works with function arguments, while `ReturnLambda()` doesn't have any of that; There's just no way to deduce the template argument `T` when invoking `ReturnLambda()`; you have to specify it explicitly. e.g.

```
auto f = ReturnLambda<int>();
```

Comment: would you please explain in detail?

Comment: The statement ` auto f = ReturnLambda();` doesn't have enough information for the compiler to know what type is T.

Comment: @fetag Answer revised; If you have problems with template argument deduction, you might want to refer to the link I posted.